# Hibernate with ZK

Tags: java, hibernate, zk

Does anyone have any experience on getting Hibernate working with ZK?

Thanks

Edit: Sorry to clarify what I am looking for:

I am looking for anyone that has experience doing this, maybe they can clarify is it easy? I have never used Hibernate before. In addition can anyone provide any resources focussed around this issue?

Comment: Do you have a particular question or are you looking for a yes or no answer? In the former case you should clarify your post to include said question, otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: Thanks ChssPly76 I have clarified the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have build an ZK Web Application totally use ZK + JSP and it works fine.
I had some problems about EntityManager life-cycle management(I needed to manage it by myself), but that was because I were not familiar with Hibernate.
To avoid any possible issue about Hibernate, I suggest you to set disable-event-thread to TRUE in zk.xml. that would save most effort and cut out the dependencies between your Hibernate usage and web app.

Answer (score 3):

I guess no answers is an answer in and of itself :-)

I haven't actually **worked** with ZK (as  in haven't deployed an actual product), but I've played with it a bit out of curiosity. Basic CRUD stuff works just fine with Hibernate, ZK has a [chapter in documentation](http://docs.zkoss.org/wiki/Hibernate) which shows how Hibernate should be set up. It's an extension of their [basic tutorial](http://docs.zkoss.org/wiki/Tutorial). ZK used to have issues with Hibernate session management but that has been resolved in the later versions (using custom ZK  listeners).

Hopefully that'll be enough to get you started. Again, I haven't done a real project with ZK so it's quite possible you'll hit on some issues once you get deeper into it - be sure to do some piloting if you're considering this for production.

Comment: The URL has changed to http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Integration/Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have used Hibernate with ZK framework. I have used mysql database in my project and everything is good with Hibernate. You can easily integrate Hibernate with ZK. Just add dependencis if your project is in maven or add Hibernate jar files in your lib folder, you have to create hibernate.cfg.xml file and put it in your project classpath i.e. inside src/main/resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article at dzone.com of zk with spring and hibernate jpa which has source code which is kept up to date with the new versions of those libraries.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-desktop-model-view